# How much of Google-Genomics is open to those studying other organisms?

Tags: google-genomics

I'm wondering how much of the Google Genomics environment is flexible enough for those who do not work on the human genome?  I couldn't find an obvious place to answer this question, and would prefer not to get too deep in and then find out its only for human.   Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Google Genomics implements the Global Alliance for Genomics and Health (ga4gh) API spec. It's designed to support genomics data from any organism.

That means, if you find anything that doesn't work for non-human data, you can file a bug as well as post to the ga4gh forums and encourage them to update the spec.

One known limitation is that if you're looking to use the "reference sets" API endpoints, there's not currently an import method defined.

The most useful APIs are for variant sets, and those should work for you for any organism.